# java - inserting and updating a table using a glassfish web service (jpa)

Tags: java, sql, web-services, jpa

i am working on a function that helps the user to transfer "money" from one account to another . this function works by removing the amount from the first account (compte1) and inserting it into the second account (compte2) and if those two accounts have different currencies it converts the amount into the currency of the second account . 
finally it adds into the table transaction , the transaction that happened and into the table transactionType the type of the transaction.
the problem that i am facing right now is that i am not able to add into the table transaction.
and so the web service is giving me the following error (everything worked until i tried to add the new transaction) :

the error in the glassfish console:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request

type Status report

messageBad Request

descriptionThe request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

the entity classes from the database are the following :
class `compte` (account) :

```
public class Compte implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 32)
    @Column(name = "typecompte")
    private String typecompte;

    @Column(name = "datecreation")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date datecreation;

    @Column(name = "montant")
    private Integer montant;

    @Column(name = "tauxinteret")
    private Integer tauxinteret;

    @JoinColumn(name = "clientid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Utilisateur clientid;

    @JoinColumn(name = "deviseid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Devise deviseid;
```

class `devise` (currency ):

```
public class Devise implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Size(max = 32)
    @Column(name = "nom")
    private String nom;

    @Size(max = 16)
    @Column(name = "symbol")
    private String symbol;

    @Column(name = "valeur")
    private Integer valeur;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviseid")
    private Collection<Transactions> transactionsCollection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviseid")
    private Collection<Carte> carteCollection;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deviseid")
    private Collection<Compte> compteCollection;
```

class `transaction` :

```
public class Transactions implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "valeur")
    private Double valeur;

    @Column(name = "transdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date transdate;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idtype", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Transactiontype idtype;

    @JoinColumn(name = "deviseid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Devise deviseid;

    @JoinColumn(name = "compteid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Compte compteid;

    @JoinColumn(name = "carteid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Carte carteid;
```

and my function is the following :

```
@GET
@Path("transaction/{id1}/{id2}/{amount}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void Transfer(@PathParam("id1") String compte1, @PathParam("id2") String compte2, @PathParam("amount") int amount) {
    ArrayList<Compte> arraycompte = new ArrayList<Compte>();
    //find compte  2 and fill the object 
    Compte c2 = new Compte();
    c2.setId(compte2);
    c2 = (Compte) (em.createNamedQuery("Compte.findById").setParameter("id", c2.getId()).getSingleResult());
    //find compte 1 and fill the object

    Compte c1 = new Compte();
    c1.setId(compte1);
    c1 = (Compte) (em.createNamedQuery("Compte.findById").setParameter("id", c1.getId()).getSingleResult());
    c1.setMontant(c1.getMontant() - amount);
    arraycompte.add(c1);
    Devise d1;
    Devise d2;

    d1 = c1.getDeviseid();
    d2 = c2.getDeviseid();

    if (d1.getId() != d2.getId()) {

        int newMontant;

        newMontant = (d2.getValeur() * amount * d1.getValeur());
        System.out.println(newMontant);
        c2.setMontant(c2.getMontant() + newMontant);
        //add compte1 in the arraylist 


        Query query1 = em.createQuery("update Compte c set c.montant=:montantVal where c.id=:compte1");
        query1.setParameter("montantVal", c1.getMontant());
        query1.setParameter("compte1", c1.getId());
        //execute update for compte 1 
        query1.executeUpdate();

        //execute update for compte 2
        c2.setMontant(c2.getMontant() + amount);
        Query query2 = em.createQuery("update Compte c set c.montant=:montantVal where c.id=:compte2");
        query2.setParameter("montantVal", c2.getMontant());
        query2.setParameter("compte2", c2.getId());
        query2.executeUpdate();

    } else {
        //add compte1 in the arraylist 

        Query query1 = em.createQuery("update Compte c set c.montant=:montantVal where c.id=:compte1");
        query1.setParameter("montantVal", c1.getMontant());
        query1.setParameter("compte1", c1.getId());
        //execute update for compte 1 
        query1.executeUpdate();

        //execute update for compte 2
        c2.setMontant(c2.getMontant() + amount);
        Query query2 = em.createQuery("update Compte c set c.montant=:montantVal where c.id=:compte2");
        query2.setParameter("montantVal", c2.getMontant());
        query2.setParameter("compte2", c2.getId());
        query2.executeUpdate();
    }
```

my problem is in the following section :

```
    Transactions t1 = new Transactions();
    t1.setCompteid(c1);
    t1.setValeur((double) amount);
    Transactiontype t1t = new Transactiontype();
    t1t.setNametransac("transfere entre compte du client");
    t1t.setCd("debit");
    t1.setIdtype(t1t);
    t1.setValeur((double) amount);
    t1.setDeviseid(d1);
    em.persist(t1t);
    em.persist(t1);
    // em.createQuery(query1).executeUpdate();
    // em.createQuery(query2).executeUpdate();


}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting in the glassfish console?

Comment: description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.